# Rails nested object returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to list the Teachers records in my app.  I have a nested Polymorphic Contact object (this is shared with Students) that is not loading when I load the Teachers.
Here are the objects:

```
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :contact, as: :contactable
    has_many :groups
    has_many :students, through: :groups
    validates :instrument, presence: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact, allow_destroy: true
end

class Contact < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :contactable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :teacher, foreign_type: 'Teacher', foreign_key: 'contactable_id', required: true

    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    validates :email, presence: true   
end
```

I load all the Teachers in my index method:

```
def index
    @teachers = Teacher.all.includes(:contact)      
end
```

And then list it out:

```
 <% @teachers.each do |teacher| %>
      <tr>
          <td>
            <%= teacher.contact.username %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= teacher.contact.email %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= teacher.contact.first_name %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= teacher.contact.last_name %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= teacher.instrument %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= link_to 'Show', teacher_path(teacher) %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_teacher_path(teacher) %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= link_to 'Destroy', teacher_path(teacher),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
          </td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
```

But I get the following error a:

```
undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
 <tr>
          <td>
            <%= teacher.contact.username %>
```

Basically, contact is empty.  I've tried every way I can think of to load it for each Teacher but nothing works.  The records are in the DB and are correct:

```
Teacher Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "teachers".* FROM "teachers"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Teacher id: 1, instrument: "Piano", created_at: "2017-03-14 18:04:30", updated_at: "2017-03-14 18:04:30">, #<Teacher id: 2, instrument: "Pia
no", created_at: "2017-03-14 18:04:52", updated_at: "2017-03-14 18:04:52">]>
2.4.0 :005 > Contact.all
  Contact Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Contact id: 1, username: "ericklind", first_name: "Erick", last_name: "Lind", email: "erick@ericklind.com", contactable_type: "Teacher", con
tactable_id: 2, created_at: "2017-03-14 18:04:52", updated_at: "2017-03-14 18:04:52">]>
```

Also, the query is selecting the records, so they should be there:

```
Started GET "/teachers" for ::1 at 2017-03-16 09:46:57 -0700
Processing by TeachersController#index as HTML
  Teacher Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "teachers".* FROM "teachers"
  Contact Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."contactable_type" = ? AND "contacts"."contactable_id" IN (1, 2)  [["contactable_type", "Teacher"]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I might have something to do with that
```
belongs_to :teacher, foreign_type: 'Teacher', foreign_key: 'contactable_id', required: true
```

It is polymorphic so you don't need to specify the association twice. Maybe it messes with the association resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see you have two records of `Teacher` but only one `Contact`.

The issue is you are looping over `Teacher.all` and `<%= teacher.contact.username %>` is raising an error for record `#<Teacher id: 1,...` as you don't have a contact present for `contactable_type = "Teacher" AND contactable_id = 2`

```
  Teacher Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "teachers".* FROM "teachers"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Teacher id: 1, instrument: "Piano", created_at: "2017-03-14 18:04:30", updated_at: "2017-03-14 18:04:30">,  #<Teacher id: 2, instrument: "Piano", created_at: "2017-03-14 18:04:52", updated_at: "2017-03-14 18:04:52">]>

2.4.0 :005 > Contact.all
  Contact Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Contact id: 1, username: "ericklind", first_name: "Erick", last_name: "Lind", email: "erick@ericklind.com", contactable_type: "Teacher", contactable_id: 2, created_at: "2017-03-14 18:04:52", updated_at: "2017-03-14 18:04:52">]>
```

You can fix it by using `:try`

```
teacher.contact.try(:username) 
teacher.contact.try(:email)
# and so on..
```

Comment: Ah!!!! Thank you! I've been banging my head on this all week and it just didn't click.  (I've been developing for years in .NET and React, and just picking up Rails so I feel a bit clumsy.)